# Laravel 5: Using SHA1 instead of Bcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, sha1, laravel-5, extending

I'm trying to extend the default Bcrypt `HashServiceProvider` in laravel 5, to make use of the SHA1 encryption instead.

Using the answer from this question: [How to use SHA1 encryption instead of BCrypt in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4) and the official documentation at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#container-based-extension, I'v managed to cook up the following code:

In **app/Providers/ShaHashServiceProvider.php**

```
    use App\ShaHasher;
    use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;

    class ShaHashServiceProvider extends HashServiceProvider {

        public function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            $this->app->bindShared('hash', function()
            {
                return new ShaHasher();
            });
        }

    }
```

In **app/ShaHasher.php**

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

    class ShaHasher implements HasherContract {

        public function make($value, array $options = array()) {
            $value = env('SALT', '').$value;
            return sha1($value);
        }

        public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
            return $this->make($value) === $hashedValue;
        }

        public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

In **app/config/app.php**

```
    'providers' => [
            ...
            //'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
            'App\Providers\ShaHashServiceProvider',
            ...
    ],
```

I'm also using Laravels out-of-the-box `AuthController` to handle logins.

But it seems that it does not work as I intended. The very first time I tried to login, everything worked perfectly fine. Then I logged out, and since then, every attempt to login has failed.

I'm not getting any errors, just the "*Whoops! There were some problems with your input. These credentials do not match our records.*" message.

I'm wondering what exactly what went wrong, and where? I hope some of you geniuses can help me out!

Comment: Why? SHA1 is not very secure.

Comment: @lukasgeiter - I'm migrating an old CakePHP App (Which uses SHA1) to Laravel 5.

Comment: Then I would try to actually migrate the passwords to bcrypt. [This answer describes how such migration process could work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519426/1903366)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'v considered that possibility as well, but I did not like the idea of changing the users schema and adding extra logic to the login process, for something that doesn't need to be that secure (in this case). I even found this guide on how to migrate the password: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/transitioning-to-bcrypt-password-while-allowing-legacy-password-hashing

Comment: In any case, I'm still curious why this code is not working :-)

Comment: Thought so... Can you figure out if it fails `check()` or if something else is causing the problem?

Comment: I'v tried to Die'n'Dump in the ShaHasher.php methods, but seems they are never called. But when I dd() in boot(), the dump is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'v solved the problem myself :-)

In **app/Providers/ShaHashServiceProvider.php** I overrided the wrong method `boot()`, when it was in fact the method `register()` I should have overridden.

```
    use App\ShaHasher;
    use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;

    class ShaHashServiceProvider extends HashServiceProvider {

        public function register()
        {
            $this->app->singleton('hash', function() { return new ShaHasher; });
        }

    }
```