# Auth::attempt() is not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

My registration form is working and it store users to db but when user login then Auth::attempt() return false. Here is my code for login. I store the password in db in sha1 encription.

```
Route::post('login',function(){
$creds=array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => sha1(Input::get('password'))
    );
$auth = Auth::attempt($creds);

dd($auth);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SHA1 encryption instead of BCrypt in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4)

Comment: see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28982706/4881811) !

Comment: why are you using sha1?

Comment: @SameerShaikh I have real users in database with sha1 encrypted password. Now I am switching from core php to Laravel. But i am stuck here in this logging.

Comment: when new users are registered, did you save passwords with `sha1` (did you modify logic related to that) ? If not, then you have existing users with sha1 and new users with default laravel encryption...

Comment: so your example to validate would fail for new users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by converting the registering user password to sha1 and then to laravel hashing encryption like so `Hash::make(sha1(Input::get('password')));`

At login time I do like below

```
Hash::make(sha1(Input::get('password')))
```

Then `$auth = Auth::attempt($creds);` worked.

Comment: @ljubadr I have converted all existing sha1 passwords to bcrypt(laravel default encryption). So password is first converted to sha1 then to bcrypt.

Comment: I suggest marking this this as an answer. Also, this answer could help someone else with the same problem in the future, so you could provide maybe a bit more explanation where did you do the changes

Answer (score 3):

Even though you can implement a Service provider as describe in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4), You can do it manually by with using [other auth method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

```
This means you can do like so:

//....
try{
    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))
      ->where('password', sha1(Input::get('password')))->firstOrFail();
    Auth::login($user);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e)
    return ['Username or password Incorrect'];
}
```

The best thing however is to use the `bcrypt()` in Laravel but the above should work in case bcrypt is no option.

Comment: When I give the right credentials it works. But When I give wrong credentials it shows "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: It shows "Sorry, the page..." because of `->firstOrFail()`.  
Change to `->first()`, but then you have to check what's in `$user`

Comment: Generally it shouldn't show that. However, using `sha1` is not okay for security concern. I specified `firstOrFail()` so that there's no need to say use any `if()` instead catch the exception else redirect user to appropriate place.

Comment: I use `firstOrFail` all the time, and it's perfect in this example (I just noticed that you catch exception, I was too tired when I looked into this). I was too focused on his comment

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi, I just added comments to his questions, maybe that's the case...

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
Route::post('login',function(){

$auth = Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')],$remember ? true : false);

dd($auth);
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: if you are using remember me check then only pass it otherwise pass it like this -
 Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')]);