# laravel 5.5 Auth::attempt login working on local server but not working on live server

Tags: php, laravel

laravel 5.5 Auth::attempt login working on local server and my another live server but not working on my server.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 1], $request->remember)) {
            $result = array('msg' => 'success');
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['msg'] = 'You have successfully!!';
            $response['url'] = url('admin');
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'error';
            $response['msg'] = 'Email and password not match!!';
        }
```

My site link:
http://giftmy.devssite.com/admin/login

Same code I've upload another server that is working
http://giftmy.webheed.com/admin/

User name: pzanwar03@gmail.com
password: 123456

Comment: Whats the error message? What do the logs say?

Comment: show login success then redirect again login page

Comment: No errors? That means your logic is flawed. i.e. server does exactly as instructed. You need to inspect each code path. Also please do not store plain-text passwords in the database.

Comment: I think it is server error. I did not find the error. my another server is working fine. but where i need to upload that server not working. you can try to login it

Comment: I will not try anything :), you need to dig for the log and show us the error. Or list the differences between the servers, PHP versions, database versions etc. If you have 1:1 copy there should not be a problem what so ever. Dig for a log and try to research it by yourself after you are done come back and ask on SO.

Comment: Maybe your session is not stored on the server correctly. Check file permissions and session configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git to deploy on server, make sure that changes made on these files are also available on  production server.

```
\vendor\laravel\ui\src\AuthRouteMethods.php

\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like a Try and Catch, this might help you with solving it.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46280152/10472503 hope that helps, if not show us the error message

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Apache version problem. I think your apache version is 2.2. You need to update 2.4.